# Usage of image-viewer tag is somewhat inconsistent - what's the best solution?

Tags: discussion, tags

In the process of removing the [images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images) tag, one of the tags I added to was [image-viewer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image-viewer). At some point, I realised that Image Viewer is often the name shown in GUI elements for the system's default image viewing application, which is often Eye of GNOME (proper tag: [eog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/eog)) but may be another program.

Checking out the posts in [image-viewer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image-viewer), it looks like many of these posts should instead be titled with the tag specific to the program, such as [eog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/eog).

I see some benefit in a general tag for image viewers (with the benefit of the experience of removing the [images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images) tag by editing all the posts), although I think perhaps [software-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) could absorb the non-specific posts if the [image-viewer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image-viewer) tag were removed. Should we remove it?

Another idea I had was renaming it to [image-viewers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image-viewers) and explaining in the usage guidance to use specific tags (eg [eog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/eog)) for questions about a particular image viewer.

Another thought I had was that it may not even matter that much that the tag is being used for image viewing programs in general and specific problems with the different default image viewing apps of each DE because these topics are related, and the use of this tag does not preclude the use of more specific tags.

What, if anything, should be done with the [image-viewer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image-viewer) tag?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest renaming it to [image-viewers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image-viewers) (and so avoid the ambiguity with `eog`) and then to follow your "Another thought..."